# MS sql db not getting connect with java app running in linux server

Tags: sql-server, linux

is there any issue if we connect java application running on tomcat container in oracle linux 7 server with ms sqk server 2016. it is working fine in localhost but not connecting with ms sql db after deploying in server

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get some kind of error message? Please edit your question to include your connection string (change passwords as necessary) and the full and complete error message - as text.

Comment: i found the issue and workaround also. issue was with connection string as we were using servername and instance name in that but since application is running inside docker container connection was not forming between application and db. "working-jdbc:sqlserver://server_ip_address:port;databaseName=dbname"; and not working -"jdbc:sqlserver://servername:instancename;databaseName=dbname";